# How to modify this Select Statement inorder to get the data using LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq

I have two data tables `LSSTiTable` and `LSSTiTable1`. I want to fetch the data from `row1` and `row2` satisfying the certain conditions.I think that the error is because `row1` and `row2` after satisfying the condition `row1` it returns three things `LDSID`,`LoopPairID`, `LocCode`. Sometimes `LocCode` returns Null Value. Hence the error. But how do i overcome that?

```
var rowData =
 (from row1 in LSSTiTable.AsEnumerable()
  join row2 in LSSTiTable1.AsEnumerable()
  on new { a = row1.Field<int>("LDSID"), b = row1.Field<byte>("LoopPairID") }
  equals new { a = row2.Field<int>("LDSID"), b = row2.Field<byte>("LoopPairID") }
  select new { row1, row2 }).ToList();
```

This is the error I get

> 'System.Data.DataRow' does not contain a definition for 'LocCode' and
>   no extension method 'LocCode' accepting a first argument of type
>   'System.Data.DataRow' could be found (are you missing a using
>   directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Code above do not produce your error. If you want to get LocCode value from row, you should use `row.Field<T>("LocCode")`

Comment: You don't show the the code where you access `LocCode`.

Comment: @lazyberezovsky i tried that..that again is an error!! :(

Comment: @drum As others have pointed out, the questions is inconsistent - you mention `LocCode`, but your code sample **never references this field**.

Comment: The error occurs later in your code, when you use the `rowData` variable. Could you post the next lines in your code?

Comment: I will request to clearly specify data and schema of your tables as a sample. LSSTiTable, LSSTiTable1, row1, row2 are really confusing. And also mention what you want to do. To me it looks like you just want to join things which is not that difficult.

Comment: "Sometimes LocCode returns null" can hardly be an explanation for that _compile-time_ error.

Comment: @Shaamaan Thats what i have asked in my question...how do i modify my code!!!

Comment: @rapsalands thats my assumption that this might be the reason ...i dont know the right solution for this !!

Comment: @rapsalands i just want to join two data tables and satisfying two conditions and while returning if a value is null that needs to be handled..here the problem is that i dont know how to handle a null value!

Comment: @Drum: Read my comments again. I am not taking about the reason. I am just saying share the exact schema and sample data so we can read the linq query better. Null should not be the issue I think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recheck whether your LDSID and LoopPairID are int and byte in your Database Tables..it could be some other type.

Comment: Yes u r right ..thank you..that was the reason,LDSID should have been short..Thank u again :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
foreach (var rowItem in rowData)
{
    var locCodeValueInRow1 = rowItem.row1[LSSTiTable.Columns["LocCode"].Ordinal];
    var locCodeValueInRow2 = rowItem.row2[LSSTiTable1.Columns["LocCode"].Ordinal];
}
```